# Function as return type Swift 4

Tags: swift

New to Swift. I am trying to understand functions as return type in Swift4. If i use the following example:

```
func functionAsAReturnType () -> ((String, String) -> String) {
    func finalString(parameter1: String, parameter2: String) -> (String) {
        return parameter1 + parameter2
    }
    return finalString
}
let finalString = functionAsAReturnType()
finalString("Hello", "World")
```

While calling the `finalString` function i am not required to provide the external parameter name.

However if i try to create the `finalString` as a separate function on its own then while calling the function i have to do something like this:

```
finalString(parameter1: 2, parameter2: 2)
```

Why is that?

With what i understood so far if there is no external parameter name, then the internal parameter name defaults as the external parameter name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - when calling a function assigned to a variable (i.e. it's been returned from another function) you don't have parameter names. Though you can still hint to callers what the parameters are meant to be using an `_` i.e. when returning a function directly

```
func userFactory(factoryName: String) -> (_ firstname: String, _ lastname: String) -> User {
    return { firstname, lastname in
        return User(factoryName, firstname, lastname)
    }
}
```

Would be called like

```
let factory = userFactory(factoryName: "Factory")

let user1 = factory("John", "Doe")
let user2 = factory("Jane", "Doe")
```

The reason that you would use parameter names while inside your `functionAsAReturnType` method is because that's a function declared in scope, not assigned to a variable e.g.

```
func userFactory(factoryName: String) -> (_ firstname: String, _ lastname: String) -> User {
    func inner(firstname: String, lastname: String) {
        return User(factoryName, firstname, lastname)
    }

    // Look, parameter names :|
    inner(firstname: "Bob", lastname: "Smith")

    return inner
}
```

However, this rule doesn't apply if you declare your function like this:

```
func userFactory(factoryName: String) -> (_ firstname: String, _ lastname: String) -> User {
    let inner = { (firstname: String, lastname: String) in
        return User(factoryName, firstname, lastname)
    }

    // No parameters names here
    inner("Bob", "Smith")

    return inner
}
```

Here, you're not calling the declaration of the func `inner` (like the last example), you're calling the variable `inner` with some parameters.

You can see this with functions which already exist i.e.

```
// Calling a function defined on Int
let i = 1
i.distance(to: 100)

// But if you assign i.distance to a variable, you don't
// use the parameter names
let f = i.distance
f(100)
```

tl;dr - if you're calling a func, use parameter names. If you're using a variable which is a function, you don't.

Not sure if this helps, if not just let me know. Also let me know if I'm wrong about any of this :)